# Server error (500) when trying to deploy django app with DEBUG=False on heroku

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy an django application on heroku. when the DEBUG variable is False, I receive a server error (500). Everything works fine when DEBUG is True. How to solve this problem ?
Here is some of the logs:

```
2021-08-17T10:15:08.603841+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.59.205 - - [17/Aug/2021:10:15:08 +0000] "GET /connexion?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.67"
2021-08-17T10:15:08.603943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/connexion?next=/" host=pnl-testapi.herokuapp.com request_id=edc211c1-244d-49ad-aac6-6e2c1d9
cf5c0 fwd="160.119.178.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=63ms status=500 bytes=403 protocol=https
```

Comment: Please, provide an error log. A 500 error means something went wrong on server side, but without having more information about the error is impossible to answer you question

Comment: Yes. This error started to get returned when I installed and configured whitenoise.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your domain in the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable in settings.py?

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']
```

Edit: You have added the access log of the webserver, please also add the exception. Have you tried running your project locally so you have quick and easy access to the console?

Comment: Here is the local error message: [17 / Aug / 2021 13:15:01] "GET / HTTP / 1.1 connection" 500 145.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for Server error (500) when trying to deploy django app with DEBUG=False on heroku

> pip install whitenoise

Edit your `settings.py` file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

If you install `django-heroku`, try to comment it out and also comment `django_heroku.settings(locals())` out.

You can turn your `DEBUG = False` and redeploy to Heroku.
This method actually worked for me. You can give it a try.

You can also read `whitenoise` documentation: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb this error is generated due to 3 things:

1.- You did not define the path for your static file directories

2.- You did not especify ALLOWED_HOST

3.- You did not install whitenoise

to solve this you have to install whitenoise and django-heroku in Python:

> pip install whitenoise
>
> pip install django-heroku

and add this in your settings.py:

```py
import django_heroku # import django-heroku


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # add your host(s)

# Add whitenoise in MIDDLEWARE
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # add this
]

# Add your paths for static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' # add this

django_heroku.settings(locals()) # add this
```

With this you need to write:

> heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0

Of this way heroku will be able to identify your static file directories.

It seems that heroku need to have reference to static file directories obligatorily.